# How i can share data which i connected with Heroku connect with other salesforce users

Tags: heroku, salesforce, heroku-postgres

I have my website in PHP and DB in MySQL. I want salesforce users to search on my database from within their salesforce. For that, heroku connect seems to be the option. So i am thinking of converting my MySQL DB to PostGre and then use heroku connect to share my data with my salesforce account. The question i have is, how can i share same data with other salesforce users ? Those users are my website clients and i don't want them to go through this process of heroku connect. Is there was of sharing my data with other salesforce users ?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot and should not expose your database directly to your customers. That would allow them to change the data as well as read it.

Your solution here is to create a public API which exposes endpoints that will make it possible for anyone (with proper authentication hopefully) to query your data.

There are many ways you can design an API, whether it's a REST or a GraphQL one. This is something which can absolutely be done in PHP though.

Comment: Yes, you are right about not exposing the DB. With public API, how can i have search filters within Salesforce that will apply on my data which i am sending through API ?

Comment: This is way too broad to be really answered. REST APIs can pass parameters in the URL or the request body. GraphQL APIs can pass parameters to the request body. Then, your codebase can read those parameters and set the matching filters.